# Dismiss PyCharm code inspection warning for particular line of code

Tags: pycharm, code-inspection

PyCharm's code inspection is a useful tool, but sometimes it gets things wrong. I know you can disable whole classes of warnings via settings, but what if you just want to dismiss a specific instance of a warning at a particular line?

Comment: **Not sure if it actually works like this in PyCharm** (not using this particular JetBrains IDE) but please try: 1) `Alt+Enter` while cursor standing on problematic place; 2) Select appropriate entry from appeared popup menu; 3) Expand submenu (click on small triangle on the right side .. or just `arrow right` key on keyboard; 4) Choose `Suppress for statement` from there. This is how it looks in **PhpStorm**: http://postimg.org/image/o4xvaapv3/

Comment: An example of pyCharm getting it wrong is when you're using class properties  and it hollars at you for not defining attributes outside of init, i.e. in init you have `self.my_property` and in the setter you do `self._my_property` By the way, it's just `option+enter` if you're on a mac.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while cursor standing on problematic place.

2. Select appropriate entry from appeared popup menu.

3. Expand submenu (click on small triangle on the right side .. or just press <kbd>arrow right</kbd> key on keyboard.

4. Choose **"Suppress for statement"** from there.

In the end special comment will be added just before that line that would temporarily turn off that specific inspection for next statement.

This is how it looks in PhpStorm (sorry, I'm not PyCharm or Python user):

[image]

Comment: Emphasis on typing **right-arrow**.  In PyCharm 4.5 clicking the small triangle does not work to install a `# noinspection` comment.  Instead it engages the default solution.

Answer (score 0):

> To just suppress the warning in the editor, there's also a lazy
> suppression option which is to use the comment noqa on the same line,
> such as:
>
> from application import routes  # noqa

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71635509/1455694)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847884/can-i-get-pycharm-to-suppress-a-particular-warning-on-a-single-line) is duplicate question that has more answers.