# PyCharm noinspection for whole file?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

Is it possible to disable an inspection for the whole file in PyCharm?

The reason this is needed is when dealing with [py.test](http://pytest.org/). It uses fixtures which appear to shadow function parameters, and at the same time cause unresolved references. e.g.:

```
from myfixtures import user  # Unused import statement warning

def test_is_awesome(user):  # Shadows name 'user' from outer scope warning
    assert user.is_awesome()
```

There is also other warnings from py.test, such as using `pytest.raises()` causes a "Can not find reference 'raises'" in pytest.py.

Maybe there's another way to fix these problems? Maybe I'm using py.test incorrectly?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is it possible to disable an inspection for the whole file in PyCharm?

Yes.

**NOTE:** This answer is for this quoted question only (and not about *"Maybe there's another way to fix these problems? Maybe I'm using py.test incorrectly?"*).

1. `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes`
2. Create a new scope that would include such "unwanted" file(s)
3. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`
4. Find that "problematic" inspection
5. Select that newly created scope in the appropriate list *(the old IDE versions had to use Right click and choose "Add scope")*
6. Disable that inspection for that specific scope.

*An example from my PhpStorm 2022.3 (would be the same or very similar in PyChram):*
[image]

[image]

**Alternatively** (should work: although this depends on the actual inspection... I'm not PyCharm user so cannot check it out)

1. Use <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while caret is standing on the error/warning place in your code (or via light bulb icon using a mouse)
2. Select correct entry from appeared popup menu
3. Using <kbd>Arrow Right</kbd> key expand the submenu (with mouse it can be quite tricky to do: the hit box is rather small)
4. Look for `Suppress inspection` option
5. It will add a special comment on the preceding line (or at the top of the file depending on what you choose) to ignore that inspection only

[image]
*(this is how it looks in PhpStorm; available options can differ between inspections)*

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20803118/783119

Comment: Thanks. This is extra handy since you can share these settings over source control.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the "Maybe I'm using py.test incorrectly?" question:

Importing fixtures is not the best pattern to follow.  Instead it is better to put fixtures in a conftest.py file of the package which needs them.  If a fixture is used in two packages just put a conftest.py in their parent directory and put the fixture in there.  This should get rid of the unused import and shadowing warnings.

As for the `pytest.raises` namespace issue, I don't think there's a solution to this currently.  This is something that pylint suffers as well (and I think there's an effort to create a py.test plugin to pylint to address these things).  So I think at the end of the day the linter will still need to know a little about py.test.

Answer (score 2):

I found that putting the per statement inspection:

```
    ...
    # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
    instance = mommy.make(Contact)
```

at the start of the file suppressed it for the whole file:

```
# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
from django.urls import reverse
```

Comment: Using PyCharm 2020.2 (Professional Edition) 
Build #PY-202.6397.98, built on July 27, 2020 and putting `# noinspection PyUnusedLocal` as the very first line of the file appears to work for me, but the file is an auto-generated settings file for jupyter. All of the lines are comments or commented out defaults, but for the one setting I had edited somewhere in the middle. Once comments are removed, that is the next statement. After editing more lines, those later lines show as having an issue.

Comment: Here is a reference for the different inspections that you can disable via `noinspection`: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#comments-ref