# PyCharm false syntax error using turtle

Tags: python, pycharm, turtle-graphics, code-inspection

The code below works perfectly, however, PyCharm complains about syntax error in `forward(100)`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from turtle import *

forward(100)

done()
```

Since `turtle` is a stanrd library I don't think that I need to do additional configuration, am I right?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `forward()` function is made available for importing by specifying [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) in the `turtle` module, relevant part from the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c7688b44387d116522ff53c0927169db45969f0e/Lib/turtle.py#L127-144):

```
_tg_turtle_functions = [..., 'forward', ...]
__all__ = (_tg_classes + _tg_screen_functions + _tg_turtle_functions +
           _tg_utilities + _math_functions)
```

Currently, pycharm cannot see objects being listed in module's `__all__` list and, therefore, marks them as an `unresolved reference`. There is an open issue in it's bugtracker:

[Make function from method: update __all__ if existing for starred import usage](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9658)

See also: [Can someone explain __all__ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)

---

FYI, you can add the `noinspection` comment to tell Pycharm not to mark it as an unresolved reference:

```
from turtle import *

#noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
forward(100)

done()
```

Or, [disable the inspection for a specific scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22959267/771848).

---

And, of course, strictly speaking, you should follow [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) and [avoid wildcard imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615125/should-wildcard-import-be-avoided):

```
import turtle

turtle.forward(100)
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to explicitly create a `Turtle` object. Then autocomplete works just as it should and everything is a bit more explicit.

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

t.left(100)
t.forward(100)

turtle.done()
```

or

```py
from turtle import Turtle

t = Turtle()
```