# "from pygame.locals import *" compiles, but produces an error

Tags: python, pycharm

I've copied the following code from a tutorial:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

This code compiles, but PyCharm insists that `QUIT` is an "Unresolved reference". Replacing `QUIT` with `pygame.locals.QUIT` obvious gets rid of this, but I'm concerned that there's something wrong with the imports. Is it that, or is PyCharm just misbehaving?

Comment: `from pygame.locals import *` will put everything in your local namespace.  Do you see the pygame.locals.quit in the output of locals()?

Comment: I guess the issue could be similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588642/pycharm-false-syntax-error-using-turtle/25588673#25588673).

Comment: That it is, and the solution works. Much obliged.

Comment: Ok, I'll mark as duplicate then. Thanks.