# File-level noinspection PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I know can prepend a type with `# noinspection PyPep8Naming`, but I couldn't figure out
how to set this globally for a single file.

I've found that this feature is present for [some other JetBrains IDEs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206358219--noinspection-for-entire-file-?page=1#community_comment_360000176664), but have failed to find this feature in PyCharm.

How can this be achieved?

**Edit:**

To clarify, I don't want to disable this inspection in my local PyCharm instance.

This file is auto-generated and I want this inspection be carried with the file to the rest of my team.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm noinspection for whole file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951489/pycharm-noinspection-for-whole-file)

Comment: @RachSharp it did not, I've edited to explain why

Answer (score 0):

Inspections in PyCharm are `For current project` only. That means each time you create new project, the settings you applied to previous project don't apply. You have to apply them again (*or change `Settings for New Projects`*).

To disable `PEP8 naming convention violation` in All Scopes, add `N801`(*class names should use CapWords convention*) to *Ignored Errors.*

Example of configuration:

[image: Configuration]

All settings you apply for current project is in same path as your project and it's called `.idea`.

Use `git status --ignored`. Folder `.idea` should be listed. Then add `.idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml`. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html#location_of_directories) is list of folders in `.idea` and what they represent.