# PyCharm disable inspection for all statements

Tags: python, pycharm

I use PyCharm and have the following file structure:

```
/common
  config.py
  glob.py
  variable.py
main.py
```

My `glob.py` is simple as this:

```
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import common.config as cfg
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import common.variable as var
```

My `main.py` can do something like this:

```
import common.glob as glob

print(glob.cfg.MY_CONSTANT)
print(glob.var.my_var)
```

The problem (or rather minor inconvenience) is that PyCharm complains about my `glob.py` imports not being used. That's not really true, because `main.py` is using them. Thus, I suppress the inspection with the comment lines `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences`.

Is it possible to effectively ignore the inspection for the whole file with a single comment?
Please avoid answers about doing this through the settings, what I'm looking for is how to make better use of these `# noinspection` rules

Comment: checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22959267/14242111 it's a little annoying but youll need to create a scope of your own and then exclude some inspections for files

Comment: Thanks, but as I noted I am looking for a solution that can be versioned in my repository, instead of a local settings change. Anyway, I'll take it that's the only way then.