# Verify the center of circle instance is a Point object, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Circle class takes Point object as the center of circle.
To verify the center of the circle instance is a Point object, I added an if not isinstance() statement in **init**. This if statement raises TypeError when center is not a Point object.

```
def __init__(self, center=(0,0), radius=1):
        Point.__init__(self,center)
        self.center=center
        self.radius=radius
        if not isinstance(center,Point):
            raise TypeError("The center must be a Point!")
```

However, the code seems to accept any tuple in the form of (x,y) to be Point object. Is there a way to only pass the Point object to be center and anything else any tuple to be TypeError?

The desired output is shown in the following:

```
>>> circle  =   Circle(center=4,    radius=1.5) 
[Traceback...] 
TypeError:  The center  must    be  a   Point!
>>> circle  =   Circle(center=Point(3,4),   radius=2) 
>>> circle.center   =   (3, 4) 
[Traceback...] 
TypeError:  The center  must    be  a   Point!
```

The following is the code for Point class:

```
import math
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.data=[x,y]
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y
    def __add__(self,other):
        return Point(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y) 
    def __mul__(self,n):
        return Point(self.x*n,self.y*n) 
    def __rmul__(self,n):
        return Point(n*self.x,n*self.y) 
    @classmethod
    def from_tuple (cls, self=(0,0)):
        return cls(*self)   
    def loc_from_tuple(self,t=(0,0)):
        self.x=t[0]
        self.y=t[1] 
    def __str__(self):
        return "Point at ({0}, {1})".format(self.x,self.y)  
    def __repr__(self):
        return"Point(x={0}, y={1})".format(self.x,self.y)
```

The following is class Circle

```
class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, center=(0,0), radius=1):
        Point.__init__(self,center)
        self.center=center
        self.radius=radius
        if not isinstance(center,Point):
            raise TypeError("The center must be a Point!")

    def __getitem__(self,item):
        return self.center[item]
    def __str__(self):
        return "Circle with center at ({0}, {1}) and radius {2}".format(self.center.x, self.center.y, self.radius)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})".format(self.center[0],self.center[1],self.radius)
    def __add__(self,other):
        return Circle(
        Point(self.center.x+other.center.x,
        self.center.y+other.center.y),
        self.radius+other.radius)
    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(cls, center,radius):
        return cls(center, radius)
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius
    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        if radius<0:
            raise ValueError('The radius cannot be negative')
        self._radius=radius
```

[This is what I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9goy.png)

Comment: Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305751/force-ensure-python-class-attributes-to-be-of-specific-type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074942/reusing-validation-logic-in-setter-and-constructor-the-right-way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825452/correct-approach-to-validate-attributes-of-an-instance-of-class

Comment: You're doing validation on the radius... why aren't you doing it on the center?

Comment: You've got the check for class Point in your initial constructor, so you check for and flag the assignment when you are CREATING the circle. The second time, you're not creating a new circle but rather updating an existing circle. So the constructor is not used, so the situation is not flagged. You would need a method for updating the value of `center`, and in that method you would need to check the class type of what's passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what's happening in your code.
When you create a circle with a center=Point (a Point object), your code create a Point with a Point as argument in center since you wrote

```
Point.__init__(self,center) # center is a Point object which is not what you want
```

This is not in accordance with the default value of center (which is a tuple), when you instantiate the Circle object with no center this will not work since the tuple center will not pass

```
isinstance(center,Point)
```

To use the inheritance, do as follow (also, not verifying that center is a tuple make more sense) :

```
class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, center=(0,0), radius=1):
        x, y = center
        super(Circle, self).__init__(x, y)
        self.center = center # This is not useful
        self.radius = radius
        if not isinstance(center, tuple):
            raise TypeError("The center must be a tuple!")

    @property
    def center(self): # This if a better way to access the center
        return(self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: x,y=center doesn't look right...Will this cause another kind of typeError, saying that integer is not iterated ?

Comment: It will work fine, in python you can do stuff like x,y=(0,0) or x,y,z=(0,0,0), etc.
Also you can verify if x,y are integer to make your code more safe.