# PyCharm does not give me the option to ignore errors for one script

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pycharm

Up until now, I've been able to right click on any errors in PyCharm and select "Ignore" from the drop down menu. However, I recently took over modifying a script that someone else wrote, and for some reason, while editing it, the option is not there. In other scripts, I can still ignore just fine.

This is the case for all types of errors.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

EDIT: I was able to suppress the errors by doing code inspection, so I no longer *need* to suppress them through the editor. However, I still would like to know why this is necessary for this specific script.

EDIT2: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847884/can-i-get-pycharm-to-suppress-a-particular-warning-on-a-single-line) provides other solutions, including the one I talked about in my first edit. However it does not address the core of my question, which is, why does Pycharm sometimes provide the option to ignore an error from the right-click drop-down menu, and sometimes not. There are ways to ignore an error without this, but I am curious why the most convenient method is sometimes absent.

Comment: Have you carefully followed the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/suppressing-inspections.html)?

Comment: The "Suppressing inspections in the editor" is what I'm trying to do. The drop-down menu lacks the option. I have not tried "Suppressing inspections from the Inspections results tool window" yet, I will try that next

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get PyCharm to suppress a particular warning on a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847884/can-i-get-pycharm-to-suppress-a-particular-warning-on-a-single-line)

Comment: Is the script in question outside of the project? I'm not sure how this actually works, but a script that's not part of the actual project seems likely to act differently.

Comment: It is. Other scripts outside the project do not have error messages at all, however.