# How to disable specific PEP8 warnings in PyCharm at the repository level?

Tags: python, pycharm

Looking to find a way, if possible, to disable specific PEP8 warnings for a Python project loaded in PyCharm at the repository level (i.e. saving a repository-committed configuration file which can apply PEP8 configuration hints to any user loading a project in PyCharm).

---

In a situation where other developers may contribute to a project using PyCharm. I personally do not use PyCharm myself (just a text editor) and building/linting is performed through various tox environments. There are select [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) rules that I am particularly not fond of, such as the promotion on injecting two blank lines in specific areas of the code (e.g. [E305](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E305.html)). While linters can be configured to ignore specific PEP8 rules and developers can invoke a command (like `tox`) with the same linter configuration, developers using PyCharm will still see these warnings in their environment. For example:

[image: PyCharm show E305 warning]

*The problem* I experience is developers will make (undesired) adjustments to the implementation and submit them for changes in pull requests. While developers can [dismiss warnings themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787218), I do not want developers to have to assume/interpret which PEP8 rules the project follows (aside from what may be mentioned in a `CONTRIBUTING` document). In addition, while source files can be modified with a `# noqa` comment to hint to the IDE to ignore an issue on that line, I am looking for an alternative way to ignore specific PEP8 rules without peppering various `# noqa` hints throughout the implementation.

For example, looking for a way to disable all `E305` warnings in a theoretical `.pycharm` file such as follows:

```
[pycharm]
ignore = E305
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) could be an option?

Comment: @OlvinRoght, thanks for the hint. However, it seems like that capability requires having a user configure their IDE. That would work for companies/groups trying to synchronize settings; but the use case I have, the repository and prospect PyCharm users not independent parties.

Comment: How about finding the pycodestyle file that comes bundled with PyCharm and editing it? With the right macro you can switch the file with a keystroke, it's a hack and not ideal but it would get the job done. What's the path to the config file in the IDE installation?

Answer (score 4):

After some additional investigation, there **does not appear to be support** (as of 2020-09-23; v2020.2) for repository-specific PEP8 warning customization.

The IDE uses `pycodestyle` for PEP8 processing. Testing out options from [pycodestyle's configuration](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#configuration) has shown that user-specific configurations will disable various PEP8 hints in the IDE; however, the goal is avoid having the user to configure anything in this case. While pycodestyle indicates that it will also look at `setup.cfg` and `tox.ini`, the IDE does not invoke pycodestyle in a way to use them. Examining [how the IDE invokes pycodestyle](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/webstorm/193.5233.13/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/validation/Pep8ExternalAnnotator.java#L204-L222) shows that it will feed a source's contents through `stdin` for information. pycodestyle only implicitly loads supported project-specific configurations (i.e. `setup.cfg` or `tox.ini`) based on a common prefix of provided input files (if provided) on the existing working directory pycodestyle is invoked on -- unfortunately, since PyCharm does not change the working directory when invoking pycodestyle to a project's root, project-specific configurations cannot be implicitly loaded.

An issue has been created on their issue tracker:

> PY-44684 | support pycodestyle project-specific configuration settings (pep8)
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44684

Answer (score 1):

There is way to do it, but at the moment it requires the corresponding PyCharm's project settings to be kept in VCS. For every reported pycodestyle.py error there is a dedicated quick fix "Ignore errors like this" that includes the respective error code in the settings of "PEP 8 coding style violation" inspection (these codes are then passed directly to pycodestyle.py via its `--ignore` option).

[image: Ignore errors like this quickfix]

You can then find and edit these codes in the inspection settings.

[image: Inspection settings]

If a per-project inspection profile was configured, these settings are saved in `.idea/inspectionProfiles/Your_Profile_Name.xml` and this way can be shared with the team or external contributors.

Obviously, it won't work if you don't want to expose IDE-specific config files in the repository, especially when there is a better, tool-independent place for such preferences. The reported [PY-44684](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44684) is a legitimate issue, I agree.